# Host key verification failed. Oracle 11g

Tags: linux, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a stored procedure in Oracle 11g. This stored procedure will copy a document between two servers (database and application) using `Executecmdwithreturn (Command);` but when I run it I get this error:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

I already generated the key for the database server.

```
Command := 'scp ' || 'carpetaServidor1 '||' ' || '/carpetaServidor2';

Executecmdwithreturn(Command);
```

Comment: This question has been getting votes for closing. I recommend the following to increase your chance of getting help: 1: provide a URL to the documentation for `Executecmdwithreturn`; 2: Provide a minimum working example of `Executecmdwithreturn` used in a way not generating errors to help determine the deltas between it working and your scenario, meaning, if this is a development environment issue there's not much we can do to help you but if it's a matter of understanding how to use `Executecmdwithreturn` then we might be able to do something.

Comment: I suppose Executecmdwithreturn executes a Host command looking at the usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and at the error i "imagine" that the problem it's not in the PL/SQL but in the scp command invoked.

Please google "scp Host key verification failed".